# Nginx redirect from one domain to dynamic domain?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have two instances of `nginx` server running one with `corporate ip` and second with `internal ip`.I want a link from external nginx get redirected to internal nginx server and use external nginx as gateway. Also need to make sure that internal nginx running on `dynamic IP`

Tried to use variable for dynamic IP as shown in code snippet

```
 location /route/(?<section>.+){
      proxy_bind 172.31.*.*;
      proxy_pass http://$section/single-table-view;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure nginx as mentioned below:

If you want to redirect your **External nginx** to **Internal nginx** you should configure your **External server** like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain_name;

        location / {

                proxy_pass http://InternalNginxIpAddress:PortYouWant;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Now each request from External nginx will be forwarded to Internal nginx, where your Internal nginx server is set as

`proxy_pass http://localhost:PortYouWant;`

Comment: so with these changes we will be able to redirect complete website but in my scenario, I just want a hyperlink get redirected to external nginx to internal nginx and as internal nginx is on private network we need to make sure external nginx work as gateway.........and how we are going to manage internal ip because in hyperlink, ip will be fetched from database through angular application(which will chnage )?

Comment: so, to create a API gateway, you can use AWS api gateways it will be best option with Angular application. https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

Comment: we are not in cloud and we dont want to create a api gateway ...we just want external nginx work as a gateway so that we can reach to internal network nginx.

Comment: please check this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IBZGS_UXhU  this might help you! Also I will update you If I get anything regarding this :)

Comment: thanks @nabeel, they have explained about API gateway and we have already implemented and its working fine but currently we are having challenge with web gateway.

Comment: thats a great news! btw what is the challenge you are facing in web gateway?

Comment: So we do have two nginx servers(one  nginx server is directly accesible from my laptop and second is not ) I just want a hyperlink get redirected to external nginx to internal nginx and as internal nginx is on private network we need to make sure external nginx work as gateway.

Comment: hey, have you resolved you web-gateway issue, if yes then please share resolution with me as I am not able to resolve that problem till now, also if the above answers has resolved your API-gateway issues you can mark this answer as correct one. Thanks :)

Comment: No still having issue